# Apply linear transformation to all elements of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a numpy array like this

```
============ arr_data
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 269.05515748   24.71801578]
 [ 276.96505874   21.72957922]
 [ 198.32475308   19.26596641]
 ...
 [ 158.11078724  -49.91437661]
 [ 219.79342843  -62.06756014]
 [  69.92358315 -166.19385119]]
('arr_data ndim: ', 2)
('         size: ', 413410)
('        shape: ', (206705, 2))
('        dtype: ', dtype('float64'))
```

Visualising this as an array of 206705 vectors (x, y), how can I apply the same linear transformation to every one of the elements in the array?

I imagine it would be a matrix multiplication with a 2x2 diagonal matrix and then adding a vector, i.e.

```
   (x', y') = ([a, 0], [0, b])(x, y) + (c, d)
```

but I don't know how this would be correctly coded. Could anyone offer any hints, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are lookig for is [np.matmul()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
import numpy as np   
a_b = np.array([[a,0],[0,b]])
x_y_new = np.matmul(x_y,a_b) + c_d
```

Make sure all the variables have the right dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, Tinu! That worked. 
`A = np.array([[1/1200.,0],[0,1.2]]) # square matrix                                                                                                     
B = np.array([640.,0.25])          # column matrix                                                                                                     
arr_data = np.matmul((B + arr_data, A) + B) # order of operations different from the example given above`